# How to write a shell script to start everything?

Tags: ros, slam, gazebo, rviz, shell

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to shell script. Is this possible to write a script basically starts for example gazebo, rviz and slam? I tried to execute command by python by you can only execute one at a time, executing next requires exiting the current one.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268337/how-to-write-a-shell-script-to-start-everything?/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-08-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can launch several nodes using a unique [launch file](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch).

For example, [this is](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/demo/demo_hector_mapping.launch) a launch file that can launch rtabmap_ros, hector_mapping, rviz and other things.

Notice the parts that start with `<node (...) >` and end with `</node>` : those mark the limits between the start of the different nodes.

Check [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/62743/how-to-create-a-launch-file/) for an answer to a similar question :-).

---

Originally posted by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) with karma: 127 on 2017-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-08**:
Also, check out [the tips for larger projects](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects). This is a far better way to go than using shell scripts. They have their place, but `launch` files are far more powerful in this context.